# Python JSON nested key value pair parsing

Tags: python, json, django, post

I am trying to make api call which has json as value to one of the keys. It is failing because of extra double quotes in inner json formed.

```
variable = request.GET.get('name', '{}')
```

This value of variable is json that is passed from webpage.

Sample data in variable will be like:-

```
variable= {'name': 'ABC', 'Id': '1'}
```

Now when I try to form my payload to be sent in post call,

```
payload = {
        'var1': var1,
        'variable': variable,
    }
```

Now this "variable" which is added to payload is treated as String and append with double quotes, like this:-

```
{'var1': '130', 'variable': "{'name': 'ABC', 'Id': '1'}"}
```

But I want it to be like this:-

```
{'var1': '130', 'variable': {'name': 'ABC', 'Id': '1'}}
```

Any suggestions how to make it possible?

this is the code to make the post call with data:-

```
r = requests.post("URL",data= json.dumps(payload),headers={'Authorization': obj.header, 'Content-type': 'application/json'}, proxies=getProxyDict())
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get `variable` from the request it isn't just 'treated' as a string... is *is* a string.

So you need to:

```
json.loads(variable)
```

before adding it to the dict which is later serialized to json.

i.e.

```
variable = json.loads(request.GET.get('name', '{}'))
payload = {
    'var1': var1,
    'variable': variable,
}
r = requests.post("URL",data= json.dumps(payload),headers={'Authorization': obj.header, 'Content-type': 'application/json'}, proxies=getProxyDict())
```

Comment: This does not solves the problem. Still double quotes are added in final payload!

Comment: are you sure you're doing `loads` and not `dumps`?  if you print `request.GET.get('name', '{}')` what do you see?  what does the final payload look like?  ... also, JSON uses double-quotes rather than single-quotes for strings

Comment: Yes I am using loads and it gives me this error:- 
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

however if I add "{" and "}" at beginning and end of this string it allows me to load it but again does not solves the problem.

Comment: If I print request.GET.get('name', '{}') it gives me this:- {'Id': '75', 'name': 'ABC'}

Comment: ok so the problem is you don't have a JSON string... can you change the place that this value comes from to output valid JSON?  to make it valid JSON they should be double-quotes instead of single-quotes... it will then be possible to use `json.loads` as per my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have presumably already dumped `variable` to a JSON string. *Don't* do that; leave it as a dict, and dump the whole thing in one go.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

variable = {'name': 'ABC', 'Id': '1'}

payload = {
    'var1': 'foo',
    'variable': variable,
}

print json.dumps(payload, indent=4)
```

results to

```
{
    "variable": {
        "name": "ABC", 
        "Id": "1"
    }, 
    "var1": "foo"
}
```

which is perfectly json. But, you may need to set your headers according to the API you're talking to.

```
request = requests.get('myurl', headers={'accept': 'application/json'})
json_data = request.json()
# manipulate json_data
request = requests.post('myurl', headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, json=json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things I would like to point here.

```
variable= "{'name': 'ABC', 'Id': '1'}"
```

This is NOT a valid json string.

```
variable= '{"name": "ABC", "Id": "1"}'
```

This is a valid json string.

So first before attaching this variable to payload dict you need to convert it to a python dict like this.

```
variable = json.loads(variable)
```

This will create variable something like this.

```
{u'name': u'ABC', u'Id': u'1'}
```

Now you can go ahead and add this to your payload dict and continue what you are doing.